# Dual monitor with different DPI causing overscan

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, xrandr, hdpi

I have a laptop with a 4k screen running Ubuntu 22.04 that I use with 200% scaling. The problem emerges when I connect a FHD (1920x1080) monitor into it.

If I let fractional scaling disabled and set scaling to 200% everything gets big on the external monitor. if I enable fractional scaling and set the second monitor to 100% I get overscan.

Here is the xrandr --verbose output: https://gist.github.com/NiloDrumond/e77816b71bdf344d5caad50a422a695d

I tried doing this (and similar configs):

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0 ; xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 7680x2160 --pos 3840x0`

Which is basically what all my research led to, but it still only shows 1/4 of my screen on the external monitor. Funnily enough, the mouse cursor seems to respect the external monitor boundaries, but the rest of the system (wallpaper and apps) don't.

If you need any more information to be able to help, please let me now and I'll be happy to provide.

PS: the "--set underscan on" command doesn't exist anymore.

PS 2: I'm using a NVIDIA gpu, but I also have Intel Integrated Graphics, if it is the onyl way.

PS 3: There are no overscan fix settings on my monitor. There is the option under aspect ratio to selected "overscan" instead of "full", but both give the same results.